# Bing speech API, Electron: "cu.connect is not a function"

Tags: javascript, electron, chromium, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I'm getting an error on line 510 (`cu.connect(source);`) of speech.1.0.0.js saying `cu.connect is not a function`.  I'm prototyping using the Bing API inside an Electron app, so this is using Chromium.  When I debug, cu is an anonymous function, and it does not have a "connect" property of any type.

Comment: PS: I'm adapting the JS sample from here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Speech-STT-JavaScript to work in Electron - really just copying and pasting the JS into my HTML, so nothing funky.    I put the call to `start()` on a button.  Clicking the button causes the error to be logged in the console.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post the debugging steps I was taking.  I debugged and finally tracked it down to the `useHttp` call on the 2nd line of `createSpeech` (line 1276), which ultimately calls `getValue` and tries to retrieve a value from localStorage.  I have nothing relevant in localStorage.  When I changed `useHttp` to just return `true`, it started working.
I'm thinking that this is because I'm using the file:// protocol inside my Electron app and so each individual file is considered a separate domain WRT localStorage.
Is there any problem forcing HTTP this way?

Comment: Edits that remove fluff [are fine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/6296561). Please refrain from further rollbacks.

Comment: @Zoe, define fluff in an entirely objective manner that everyone agrees with and I'll stop rolling back edits that are useless and harm the overall user experience

Comment: @TimTheEnchanter It doesn't matter if "everyone agrees". There are quality standards set by the community through discussion on Meta, and those are clear on the topic at hand. If you want to adjust the standards, start a discussion on Meta, otherwise, please respect the existing ones.

Comment: There's an awful lot of dissension in those meta discussions, but sure, you keep telling yourself that "the community" has spoken and decided that basic manners are fluff. It seems to me that this is a random edict handed out by a small percentage of people.  We're talking about 9 characters here.  And rather than answering questions that would *gasp* help people,  some folks have decided it's more valuable to remove those 9 characters from my posts.  That makes total sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ultimately came down to using the file:// protocol inside Electron.  Changing the `useHttp` function (line 211) to just return `true` fixed it.

So, change line 211 from:

`return getValue("useHttp");`

to:

`return true;`

and things will start working.  I'm still trying to figure out whether forcing Http this way is going to cause any side effects (it doesn't appear to so far).